# Is it possible to delete files based on there output(readelf based) in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, elf

**root@kali:~/Downloads/Malware_subsets/Subset1# readelf -S file1_100**

There are 10 section headers, starting at offset 0xc278:

**root@kali:~/Downloads/Malware_subsets/Subset1# readelf -S file1_12**

*There are no sections in this file.*

So I want to write a script:
that can help me to delete all the file in my directory with this output "*There are no sections in this file.*

Comment: Please copy&paste code and text output **as text** instead of showing a screenshot. It is unclear what you are asking. Please explain in detail what you want to achieve. (Of course it is possible to write a shell script that deletes files depending on the output of `readelf`.)

Comment: I got a folder where multiple elf files exist when I used readelf -S file1_12 for file number 12. the output was there are no sections in this file. But when i did it for file1_11 it give details. So i want to keep fille 11 and delete file 12. Note: I have almost 1000 files in that folder

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Logic :

```
boo=$(date) 

echo $boo
Wed Sep 23 08:17:24 EDT 2020

if [[ $boo == Wed* ]] ; then echo True ; fi
```

Applying same logic to your requirement (modify the string based on your requirement ) :

```
file_name=<filename>

result=$(readelf -S $file_name)

if [[ $result == "There are no secontions in this file." ]] ; then rm -f $file_name ; fi
```